# SUMIFS Formula not working correctly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a SUMIFS formula below and it does not seem to be working correctly any help would be greatly appreciated.

The formula is below

```
=SUMIFS(C4:N4,C4:N4,C4<=11,C4:N4,F4<=1,C4:N4,I4<=1,C4:N4,L4<=1)
```

From the picture you can see that the result in cell R4 should read 4 but it returns a 0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SumIfs works with **sum_range, criteria_range, criteria.**

You've given it **sum_range, criteria_range, criteria_cell & criteria.**

Try `=SUMIFS(C4:N4,C4:N4,"<=1")`, or as it's only a single criteria `=SUMIF(C4:N4,"<=1",C4:N4)`

**Edit:**  Just noticed - is that first criteria meant to be <=11?
If so this formula will work:  `=SUM(IF(C4<=11,C4,0),SUMIF(F4:N4,"<=1",F4:N4))`

Comment: Thank you for the help `=SUM(IF(C4<=11,C4,0),SUMIF(F4:N4,"<=1",F4:N4))` works really well. I was wondering if I may set you another challenge In Cell S4 I would like to sum or total if C4 is between 11 and 19 and F4 is between 2 and 20 and I4 is between 2 and 20 and L4 is between 2 and 20.

Is this possible? Thanks again for all the help .

Comment: Off the top of my head this would work:  `=SUM(IF(AND(C4>=11,C4<=19),C4,0),IF(AND(F4>=2,F4<=20),F4,0),IF(AND(I4>=2,I4<=20),I4,0),IF(AND(L4>=2,L4<=20),L4,0))`.  I've got a feeling there should be a better way though.

Comment: Unfortunately `=SUM(IF(AND(C4>=11,C4<=19),C4,0),IF(AND(F4>=2,F4<=20),F4,0),‌​IF(AND(I4>=2,I4<=20)‌​,I4,0),IF(AND(L4>=2,‌​L4<=20),L4,0))` Thank you for the attempt though. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what's unfortunate....  Didn't it work as you'd planned?  Actually - I just copied it and pasted and there were some strange I bars placed in the formula with invisible characters so it gave a _formula contains errors_ message.  Each part of the formula should be in the format `IF(AND(C4>=11,C4<=19),C4,0)` - if between 11 & 19 inclusive then use the value of C4 in the sum, otherwise use 0. Then just sum the results.

Comment: @ Darren Bartrup-Cook Thanks for the help this is what ended up working for me. `=SUM(AND(C4>=12,C4<=19)*C4,AND(F4>=2,F4<=20)*F4,AND(I4>=2,I4<=20)*I4,AND(L4>=2,L4<=20)*L4)` Thanks so much for all the help. I hope you got some good Stackoverflow points from today. Much respect from Dublin :-)

Comment: That'll work - `AND(C4>=12, C4<=19)` will return TRUE (1) or FALSE (0) it then multiplies by the value in C4 so either C4*1 or C4*0. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `SUMIFS` means that you want to add the values in `C4:N4` only if all conditions are TRUE. If this is correct use this formula.

`=IF(AND(C4<=11,F4<=1,I4<=1,L4<=1),SUM(C4:N4),0)`

'SUMIFS' is intended for operations with ranges in which one column is added if all condition in other columns are met see [WorksheetFunction.SumIfs Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193011.aspx) . But in your case you are testing conditions in a row and if they are met you want to add the values in the row.

Comment: That formula will fail if one of the values is FALSE.  If `F4` is 2 the formula returns 0 rather than 3 (I think that's how the OP wants it to work).  The columns/rows doesn't matter with SUMIFS, as the help page states: _Each criteria_range does not have to be the same size and shape as sum_range. The actual cells that are added are determined by using the top, left cell in that criteria_range as the beginning cell, and then including cells that correspond in size and shape to sum_range._ (which is confusing in itself).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook it seems that you did not read my first statement...

Comment: I read it, just misunderstood it.  SUMIFS will add the values in C4:N4 that meet all the criteria for that cell, or if you prefer, each cell in sum_range is summed only if all of the corresponding criteria specified are true for that cell.